# Air purifier got stepped on, power cord chipped

Tags: electrical, wiring

[image] [image]

<sup>Click for larger images</sup>
So late at night I stepped on my air purifier cord and it broke the power plug from inside! When I went to open it up i heard the little chip or box that holds the power outlet had got chipped off.

Does anyone know if I can just black tape it together or will it need a hands on professional? I got it together but just a bit skeptical about to connecting to power so if anyone can let me know that would be cool. Thanks!

Comment: i do not see a picture ... have you actually looked at what you posted?

Comment: No picture yet.   Will need to see before any answer.

Comment: if someone here says *"sure, you can tape that up"*, and then your house burns down, do you think that your insurance company will say *"no problem with paying your claim, because the guy on the internet said it's ok"*

Comment: There it’s up. And c’mon like I don’t expect my house to blow …. Well to play it safer I’ll just connect to a power bank because it is usb powered as well so if anything that blow to hell 

Answer (score 4):

That is a low voltage connector.  No "burn house down" worries here.

Actually, it is a printed circuit board *which holds* the connector.  That is cracked.

If you can use wire and solder to duplicate the cracked printed circuit traces, you should be able to bring the unit back to life.

Or you could buy that same Molex connector in chassis-mount form, on mouser.com, and drill a new hole in the chassis and mount it there.

This is all low-voltage low power stuff, otherwise I would *not* be suggesting that you experiment as a novice.

Comment: Nice, this is my guy right here thank bro your a real one. Now I know what to call it instead of green thing 

Answer (score 2):

Harper's answer will work just fine; but there's an alternative, as we're only playing with low voltage.

Trace precisely which wires [red/black] go to which terminals of the socket itself, then solder them directly to the socket tabs instead of the PCB. That way the PCB becomes simply a passive mount for the actual socket, & you can glue or tape it as necessary in order to keep it stable.

Guessing, because I can't see the wires or PCB traces clearly enough to be absolutely certain, but it looks like the red goes to the centre rear & the black to *both* the centre front and side tabs. [Double check to be sure.]
You could then glue in the gap between PCB & socket, indicated in green…

[image]

<sup>Click for larger image</sup>